# Linux - make install without replacing symlinks

Tags: symbolic-link, make, makefile

I recently (and foolishly, since there is a simple solution here, had I set `--prefix=` option to something other than it's default `/usr/bin`) `configure`d and `make`d `gcc-4.9.1`, without setting the `--prefix=` option. I don't really want to re`make` the whole thing, since it will take a decently large chunk of time.

My `/usr/bin/` directory already contains `gcc-4.8.2`, as installed by the OS (Ubuntu-14.04). The key point is that the existing symlinks are all pointing to things like `gcc-4.8`, and will be replaced upon the command `make install` by symlinks to `gcc-4.9`, `g++-4.9` etc.

Can I pass an argument to `make`, telling it to not replace symlinks which already exist? Or similar?

Comment: Let's just clarify something; you want to just not overwrite the existing installation of GCC, correct? Would installing the new files into a different directory (as if you had used `./configure --prefix=$something`) be an acceptable substitute? Please [edit] to indicate your answer.

Comment: I would imagine that would have worked out fine for me - I could then have either added the new directory location to path or symlinked as I chose. Now, I have to either `install` and relink the `4.8.2` binaries, or find some more inventive solution. I'm here looking for said more inventive solution. Either way, question edited to try clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, note that [**the default prefix**](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Default-Prefix.html#Default-Prefix) unless one is explicitly specified is most often /usr/local. So overwriting the installation in /usr might not even be an issue in your case, although it could certainly cause confusion down the road having one GCC in /usr and another in /usr/local.

While I am not certain whether it works specifically with gcc-4.9.1 (although I see little reason it wouldn't), autoconf (which generates the `configure` script) provides facilities for **overriding the prefix at installation time.**

Quoting the [autoconf documentation, section "installation names"](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Installation-Names.html#Installation-Names):

> The most portable way to affect installation locations is to pass the correct locations to configure; however, many packages provide one or both of the following shortcuts of passing variable assignments to the ‘make install’ command line to change installation locations without having to reconfigure or recompile.
>
> The first method involves providing an override variable for each affected directory. For example, ‘make install prefix=/path/to/alternate’ will choose an alternate location, as well as influencing all other directory configuration variables that were expressed in terms of ‘${prefix}’ (or, put another way, all directories specified during configure but not in terms of the common prefix must each be overridden at install time for the entire installation to be relocated). The approach of makefile variable overrides for each directory variable is required by the GNU Coding Standards, and ideally causes no recompilation. However, some platforms have known limitations with the semantics of shared libraries that end up requiring recompilation when using this method, particularly noticeable in packages that use GNU Libtool.
>
> The second method involves providing the ‘DESTDIR’ variable. For example, ‘make install DESTDIR=/path/to/alternate’ will prepend ‘/path/to/alternate’ before all installation paths. The approach of ‘DESTDIR’ overrides is not required by the GNU Coding Standards, and does not work on platforms that have drive letters. On the other hand, it does better at avoiding recompilation issues, and works well even when some directory options were not specified in terms of ‘${prefix}’ at configure time. For packages which support ‘DESTDIR’, the variable should remain undefined during configure and ‘make all’, and only be specified during ‘make install’.

So `make install DESTDIR=/opt/gcc-4.8.2` *should* do pretty much what you are after. You may need to move files around slightly afterwards depending on the exact directory structure you want, but it should be good enough for a start.

Note that I haven't tested this; you run it at your own risk.